# Jquery checking if user scrolled to bottom works reversed

Tags: jquery

I have got this code in three different js files
        var sd=0;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
               if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                sd++;
                          $.ajax({
                            url: '../connect.php',
                            type: 'GET',
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data:"SMu=true&&sd="+sd,                         
                            success: function(d)
                            {    
                                $(".upfile").append(d);
                                $(".ShowMoreUpl").remove();
                            }   
                        });
               }
            });
```

In one file it works quintessentially while in other it works when i scroll to the apex.What may be the reason that causes this problem?

Comment: Use if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())==$(document).height())

Comment: Three different files? Do they end up on same pages? Otherwise what is different about the pages themselves? Or what is different between instances of this code?

Comment: Nothing really this js code is in my two different .js files but i use it in my three different .php files @charlietfl

Comment: @NagaSaiA same result

Comment: Well clearly something is different and we have no way to know what that is from what is shown. All we can do is guess which isn't how this should work. See [mcve]. Try to make demos that reproduce issue. Also remove other code in various pages and see if that does anything

Comment: Also try logging the values being compared and see what that produces.

Comment: The problem is in both files that do not work window height is equal to document height.May that be because they are both included? @charlietfl